# Finding invariant when detecting a cycle

Tags: algorithms, correctness-proof, loop-invariants

Let consider a connected graph $G = (V, E)$ which is not oriented. One way to detect a cycle in such a graph is :

> 1. Create an array : **seen** of size $\mid V \mid$ with **seen[i] = false** for all $i$
> 2. Perform a DFS (or BFS) starting at the node $0$.
> 3. When we see a node $i$ : we have two cases : if **seen[i] = false** then **seen[i] = true** else we found a cycle.

One idea to prove the correction of this algorithm is saying the following : if the algorithm return true it means there two  nodes $x$ and $y$ such that when we looked at $y$ we have : **seen[y] = false** and **seen[x] = true** thus there is a cycle namely the cycle which begin at $x$ and use the only path that connect $x$ and $y$ in the DFS tree and then use the edge $(y,x)$.

The problem is that this is not really rigourous and I am really lokking for an invariant that we help me do the correction of this algorithm rigourously.
So is there any invariant I can use here ?

Thank you very much  !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we execute line 3 when you first visit a node, and assuming you are working with directed graphs, this algorithm is incorrect (consider what happens with a cross edge discovered by DFS).

Alternatively, assuming you are working with undirected graphs:

The missing part of your argument is the "thus" part; why does the existence of two such nodes imply the existence of a cycle?

To work out the proof, I suggest categorizing what types of edges can exist in the search tree for an undirected graph: tree edges? forward edges? back edges/ cross edges?  Then, categorize what type of edge caused you to visit x when seen[x] was true.  What does that mean the search tree has to look like?

Comment: Yes I am working with undirected graph. Actually I understand how the algorithm work (intuitively) but I  am not able to find a correct **invariant** that will help me do the correction.

Comment: @1597846254899, yes, and I am giving you guidance on that will hopefully help you work out a proof of correctness, if you spend some time thinking about it.  I suggest you spend some time working through the details in the last paragraph of my answer, and make sure you can answer all of the questions I listed in the last paragraph of my answer.